# Как лучше создавать функцию?

Tags: функции, kotlin

Как лучше объявлять функцию: через выражение

```
fun f() {
    ...
}
```

или анонимной лямбдой?

```
val f = {
    ...
}
```

И в чем преимущества?

Comment: я думаю стоит взглянуть сюда -> https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#:~:text=Kotlin%20functions%20are,lambda%20expressions.

Comment: Лямбду имеет смысл использовать только когда имя не важно. В общем-то у второго варианта никаких особых преимуществ нет.

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя сказать что "одно лучше другого", то и то является функциями, но есть различия.

- Анонимные функции позволяют указывать тип возвращаемого значения, а
  лямбда-выражения — нет
- Анонимная функция все еще является функцией, поэтому возврат из нее ведет себя так же, как возврат из любой функции. Однако возврат из лямбды на самом деле возвращает функцию, содержащую лямбду

---

**UPD1**

Если задавать функцию через выражение, то её можно лаконично уместить в одну строчку без явного упоминания `Return` (но с явным упоминанием типа):

```
fun add(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
```

---

**UPD2**

Из того что написано выше, можно, кстати, сделать вывод о том, что лямбду можно передавать как аргумент для другой функции, что даёт гибкости *(наверное)*.

Тем не менее, с анонимными лямбдами возможны следующие конструкции:

```
fun performOperation(a: Int, b: Int, operation: (Int, Int) -> Int): Int {
    return operation(a, b)
}

fun main() {
    val result = performOperation(5, 3) { x, y -> x + y }
    println(result) // Выводит: 8
}
```

В функции `main()` мы вызываем `performOperation` и передаем анонимную лямбду `{ x, y -> x + y }` в качестве аргумента `operation`. Это лямбда-выражение складывает два числа. В результате мы получаем сумму `5 + 3`, равную `8`, которую выводим на консоль.

Comment: Автор мне кажется немного о другом...

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja субъективно будет давать свое решение о том что "лучше" в данной ситуации, я лишь описал конкретные различия между двумя разными методами задачи функции в kotlin)